# How to render vision, based on the motion in the environment?

Tags: unity-game-engine, opticalflow

I have a game idea, where your character's vision is based completely on the motion in the environment.

I am just interested in prototyping this idea and see the result, however I have no idea how to approach to the "vision based on motion" algorithm.

I appreciate any guidance to where to start to research as much as direct answers to solution.

To give details about the problem;

-The characters vision is limited to the motion in the environment. If a ball moves inside the frustum, only the motion of the ball would be visible, everything else would be dark.

-If the character rotates, since from the frustum's view of reference, the whole scene would be seem like moving, character would see the whole environment as long as it keeps rotating. And everything should be return to black, when it stops rotating. Same also applies if character moves in to any direction. As long as the frustum moves, the environment would be moving according to frustum's view of reference, thus the motion is achieved.

So to think about it, the simplified version of problem is(?) to show any update in the screen to player, and darken out everything else.

As I have told, I am only interested in prototyping it, I haven't really think about how the gameplay would come up to be. However If you have any foresight about how nonsensical the gameplay would be, I also would like to hear about it from you.

Thank you in advance.

PS: I am not sure about the tags, so If you can add corresponding tags to question, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Great idea! Use **[`Renderer.motionVectors`](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/Renderer-motionVectors.html)** pass introduced around Unity 5.4. It probably stands there for motion blur purposes, but could be a great fit for your prototype.

A custom pass that simply multiplies the beauty render with desaturated motion vector values could do the trick.

Please get back with any progress!

May read more on [Optical Flow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow), and [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html) in general.

Comment: I think this won't work if the objects are static and the camera moves, right? Maybe reading all the pixels on screen and then compare with the pixels on the previous frame? I know it's a really slow operation but maybe it's a path worth to be explored.

Comment: @JonasGrumann well, it says "in addition to the default camera reconstruction motion vectors". Per object seems to point that the entire effect can be included / excluded to be rendered per object. **Go ahead and try**. Anyway, never late to move the entire scene instead of camera if that works.

Comment: @JonasGrumann Pixel comparison: this is what Optical Flow does, and what Motion Vectors spares. :)

Comment: I understand that, but will Motion Vectors work if no object is moving except for the camera?

Comment: @JonasGrumann I did not used motion vectors yet, but why don't you just render something and see?

Comment: Can't, I'm at work :) but I will try it out tonight.

Comment: Until that, vote here please :D http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288030/update-app-icons

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe sounds like you are interested in [motion detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_detection) not in [motion estimation/tracking/optical flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow).

In a sense, you can always get motion detection from a motion estimation technique, but the result will take longer to estimate (optical flow techniques in particular are known to be slow). Also, certain methods are available when you relax the problem.

With that said, an interesting source of inspiration for your project may come from the encoding side... perhaps something you have not considered.

If your system are using reasonable encoders for the video, such as h264, h265, vp8 or vp9, chances are that you may have the information you are looking for... FOR FREE. The motion is part of the efficient transfer of the video. If you can hack the decoder on the receiving side, you may get the information together with the generated frames. You can then "easily" remove patches where the change factor is small. The benefit of doing it this way would be that you would need neglible cpu or memory resources, and that the lag time would be essentially zero (which would not be the case with optical flow).

The downside is that the motion that is inherent in many decoders are quite unreliable for anything else than encoding, but that may be overcome with some smart signal processing tricks

good luck, cool idea :)